# Default landing page asp.net web api published IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have created a .Net project 4.6 using web api.

just for simplicity purpose, I created default.htm in the parent directory. I publish my project to localhost, and set up the default document to default.htm as per the screenshot:[image]

[image]

published web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

However, whenever I navigate to http://localhost/, it always returns 404 as per the screenshot below: Can someone please help? Thanks

[image]

I am using port 80:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All published Web Site in IIS need to have a port like this:

```
1.Assuming you are using the port of 8462.
2.Try to navigate this url =  localhost:8462
```

Make sure your asp.net has been registered to your IIS like this [aspnet_regiis -i](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx)

Good Luck!